# Does the infinite series $\sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]{ln(n)}}$ converge absolutely / converge / diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Does the infinite series $\sum_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[n]{ln(n)}}$ converge absolutely / converge / diverge?

I can show the the positive and negative element series diverge, so I know the series does not converge absolutely, but I don't know how to tell if it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\ln n}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\to 1$$

then the series doesn't converge.

Comment: I actually thought of this but for some reason just forgot to apply that my original series is larger then this series (brain fart). Thanks!

Comment: @Jason Yes it is always the first check to do!

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{\ln n}} = e^{-\frac{1}{n}\ln\ln n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} e^0 = 1
$$
so the general term does not converge to $0$: the series diverges by the [term test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_test).

Comment: This leads the OP so faster.